# What does "Server Temp Key" mean in an openssl output?

Tags: tls, openssl, diffie-hellman

I am using openssl 1.0.1e-fips. When I ran the following against my server, I get a line in the output that begins with `Server Temp Key`:

```
$ openssl s_client -cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA -connect myserver.com:443 -state -tls1 -msg
...snipped...
Server Temp Key: DH, 2048 bits
...snipped...

$ openssl s_client -cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA -connect myserver.com:443 -state -tls1 -msg
...snipped...
Server Temp Key: ECDH, prime256v1, 256 bits
...snipped...
```

Can I conclude that `ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA` is "weaker" than `DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA` given that its length is smaller than 2014 bits ? Is the Server TEMP key the negotiated protocol key i.e. the session key.

Comment: See http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25577/ecc-vs-rsa-how-to-compare-key-sizes and canonically http://www.keylength.com . The DHE _result_ (not the server key) is used as the premaster secret, which is used to _derive_ the session key values (always at least 2, and for the ciphersuites you named either 4 or 6) see http://security.stackexchange.com/a/138559/39571

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ephemeral (= temporary) key used for [Diffie Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).

You should configure it to be as strong as the key for the certificate.

DHE with 2048 bits provides [112](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_size#Asymmetric_algorithm_key_lengths) "bits of security". ECDHE with 256 bits provides [128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography#Key_sizes) "bits of security". So ECDHE over P-256 is more secure than 2048 bit DHE. There are also fewer bad implementations of ECDHE and TLS allows to negotiate its strength (the curve), which is why [Google Chrome removed support for DHE](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/ShRaCsYx4lk) so you should switch to ECDHE (i.e. make the server support and prefer ECDHE).

Comment: See here for more pointers on configuring dhparams https://stackoverflow.com/a/64581683/